# Altering the font size (and, if possible, other font formatting attributes) of the Shell class' back button's overridden text

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a `ContentPage` (that is a content of the sub-classed `Shell` class) which, when viewed requires a back button with a specific string text to be present in the navigation bar.

```
<ContentPage 
    ....>
  <Shell.NavBarIsVisible>True</Shell.NavBarIsVisible>
    <Shell.BackgroundColor>Black</Shell.BackgroundColor>
    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="True" 
                            TextOverride="A" />
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
  
   .....

</ContentPage>
```

The back button with the required text is displayed as expected in the navigation bar, but the text is not quite in the required font size in the Android platform.

As always with such problems, I attempted to resolve the issue by using a custom shell renderer for the Android platform (as seen below), but I am not able to fathom the way to alter the font size of the text of the back button.

```
class ShellRenderer
            : ShellRenderer
{
    public ShellRenderer
            (Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker 
        CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker()
    {
        return new CustomToolbar(this);
    }
    
    public class CustomToolbar 
                  : ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public CustomToolbar
               (IShellContext context) : base(context) 
        { 
        }

        public override void SetAppearance
          (AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar,
           IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, 
           ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance
                (toolbar, toolbarTracker, appearance);

            // How do you increase the font size of the back button??
            
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding break point in SetAppearance method, and you can see A is display in **toolbar.NavigationIcon**, it is not public member, I think it is not modified.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upon analyzing the instance of the `AndroidX.AppCompact.Widget.Toolbar` class present as an argument of the overridden `SetAppearance()` method (by placing a breakpoint in the said method), it can be seen that the font size of the back button's overridden text is set via the private field named `_defaultSize`(having its value set to 50) present in the object (of type `Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable`) corresponding to the `NavigationIcon` attribute.

As the field concerning the alteration of the font size is not declared as a public member and has no helper properties/methods, one must use reflection to set its value to the required font size as follows:

```
int requiredFontSize = 100;
toolbar.NavigationIcon.GetType()
   .GetField("_defaultSize", 
             BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
   .SetValue(toolbar.NavigationIcon, requiredFontSize);
```

Comment: glad to hear that you have solved your problem, you can mark your reply as answer, it maybe help others.